# Assignment to a data.frame with `with`

Tags: r

Here's an example that assigns in two different ways, one which works and one which doesn't:

```
library(datasets)
dat <- as.data.frame(ChickWeight)
dat$test1 <- with(dat, Time + weight)
with(dat, test2 <- Time + weight)
> colnames(dat)
[1] "weight" "Time"   "Chick"  "Diet"   "test1"
```

I've grown accustomed to this behavior.  Perhaps more surprising is that `test2` just disappears (instead of winding up in the base environment, as I'd expect):

```
> ls(pattern="test")
character(0)
```

Note that with is a fairly simple^H^H^H^H^H^H short function:

```
function (data, expr, ...) 
eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
```

First let's replicate with's functionality:

```
eval( substitute(Time+weight), envir=dat, enclos=parent.frame() )
```

Now test with a different enclosure:

```
testEnv <- new.env()
eval( substitute(test3 <- Time+weight), envir=dat, enclos=testEnv )
ls( envir=testEnv )
```

Which still doesn't assign anywhere. This disproves my hunch that it was related to the enclosing environment being discarded, and rather points to something more fundamental to the `,enclos` argument not doing what I think it does.

I'm curious about the **mechanics** of why this is going on and if there's an **alternative** which allows assignment.

Comment: Your last example doesn't modify `dat` because `dat` isn't an environment. At best it would get coerced via `as.environment` to an environment, modified, and then promptly discarded, since there are no other references to it, leaving the original `dat` unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

Change `with` to `within`. `with` is only for making variables available, not changing them.

Edit: To elaborate, I believe that both `with` and `within` create a new environment and populate it with the given list-like object (such as a data frame), and then evaluate the given expression within that environhment. The difference is that `with` returns the result of the expression and discards the environment, while `within` returns the environment (converted back to whatever class it originally was, e.g. data.frame). Either way, any assignments made within the expression are presumably performed inside the created environment, which is discarded by `with`. This explains why `test2` is nowhere to be found after doing `with(dat, test2 <- Time + weight)`.

Note that since `within` returns the modified environment instead of editing it in place (i.e. call-by-value semantics), you need to do `dat <- within(dat, test2 <- Time + weight)`.

If you want a function to do assignment to the current environment (or any specified environment), look at `assign`.

Edit 2: The modern answer is to embrace the tidyverse and use magrittr & dplyr:

```
library(datasets)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
dat <- as.data.frame(ChickWeight)
dat %<>% mutate(test1 = Time + weight)
```

The last line is equivalent to

```
dat <- dat %>% mutate(test1 = Time + weight)
```

which is in turn equivalent to

```
dat <- mutate(dat, test1 = Time + weight)
```

Use whichever of the last 3 lines makes the most sense to you.

Comment: Helpful, but `within` is a lot less generic than `with`, and I'm curious why it was necessary to have a separate function for it.  Specifically, `within` assigns to a specific column of a data.frame via `data[nl] <- l`.  There's no `within` method to assign to an environment, but I guess you could just use `eval` directly for that?

Comment: The advice is wrong. `within` does NOT assign to columns outside of its environment. You need to do: `dat$test2 <- with(dat, Time + weight)` OR `dat <- with(dat, test2 <- Time + weight)`

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wrote my original answer on my mobile phone and couldn't elaborate sufficiently.

Comment: Great answer, and helpful, but still doesn't really solve the assignment problem.  Maybe the answer is, "Not possible--give up on your pipe dream?" :-)

Comment: You could write a function that works like `within`, but instead of taking a list-like first argument, takes a variable name. Then the function could extract the value bound to that variable name in the calling environment (using `get`), use that value in the call to within, and then assign the result to the same variable name in the calling environment using `assign`.

Comment: In other words, you could do something like `modify.within <- function(varname, expr) assign(varname, within(get(varname, ...), expr), ...)`, where `...` are the proper arguments to specify the calling environment, which I always forget how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the fact that the following works from the command line ...

```
eval(substitute(test <- Time + weight, dat))
```

... I put together the following, which seems to work.

```
myWith <- function(DAT, expr) {
    X <- call("eval", 
              call("substitute", substitute(expr), DAT))
    eval(X, parent.frame())
}

## Trying it out
dat <- as.data.frame(ChickWeight)
myWith(dat, test <- Time + weight)
head(test)
# [1]  42  53  63  70  84 103
```

(The complicated aspect of this problem is that we need `substitute()` to search for symbols in *one* environment (the current frame) while the "outer" `eval()` assigns into a *different* environment (the parent frame).)

Comment: I should probably add that *using* a function that performs non-local assignments as a side-effect like this is a pretty bad idea, in my opinion. Still, interesting to see that it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

I get the sense that this is being made way too complex. Both `with` and `within` return values calculated by operations on named columns of dataframes. If you don't assign them to anything, the value will get garbage collected. The usual way to store tehn is assignment to to a named object or possibly a component of an object with the `<-` operator. `within` returns the entire dataframe, whereas `with` returns only the vector that was calculated from whatever operations were performed on the column names. You could, of course, use `assign` instead of `<-`, but I think overuse of that function may obfuscate rather than clarify the code. The difference in use is just assignment to an entrire dataframe or just a column:

```
 dat <- within(dat, newcol <- oldcol1*oldcol2)
 dat$newcol <- with(dat,  oldcol1*oldcol2)
```